# Backbiting : doubts on it

Tags: islamic-basis, backbiting

Assalamualaikum, recently, i have learned that backbiting is a major sin. I have doubts on it & some more issues added based on islam.Here they are:

Doubt 1. If i backbit someone accidentally or intentionally, do i have to reach out to them even if it's awkward because they don't know me and they are out of my reach? Let me give you an example. My friend had talked about a neighbour living next to us- we both know him. She talked some things about him- though i wasnt sure she would talk bad things or so. Also, I had listened to her words so i bear the same sin as her but its unintentional and accident. What do i do?  Also, even if jt is backbiting, Its awkward to seek forgiveness because he doesnt know us since we are strangers. He might get shocked  and mom warned us not to talk or visit any strangers house, so it's not possible to ask forgiveness however. Am i forgiven if i just ask forgiveness from Allah?

Answer (score 0):

> يَـٰٓأَيُّهَا ٱلَّذِينَ ءَامَنُواْ ٱجۡتَنِبُواْ كَثِيرٗا مِّنَ
> ٱلظَّنِّ إِنَّ بَعۡضَ ٱلظَّنِّ إِثۡمٞۖ وَلَا تَجَسَّسُواْ وَلَا
> يَغۡتَب بَّعۡضُكُم بَعۡضًاۚ أَيُحِبُّ أَحَدُكُمۡ أَن يَأۡكُلَ لَحۡمَ
> أَخِيهِ مَيۡتٗا فَكَرِهۡتُمُوهُۚ وَٱتَّقُواْ ٱللَّهَۚ إِنَّ ٱللَّهَ
> تَوَّابٞ رَّحِيمٞ 12
> You who believe, refrain from conjecturing too much: even a little
> suspicion forms a vice . Do not spy on one another, nor let any of you
> **backbite** others. Would one of you like to **eat his dead brother's flesh**? You would loathe it! Heed God, for God is Relenting,
> Merciful! [(12)](https://quran.inoor.ir/en/ayah/49/12/)

Penance of Backbiting

> To make amends for it, one must feel regret and
> repent from the sins of backbiting. Then, he must curry favor with the
> one he backbit and ask him for acquittal. If the backbitten forgives,
> it will be satisfactory. If not, to curry favor with him and apologize
> will be equivalents of the commitment of backbiting. The previous acts
> should be done when the backbitten is alive and when such confessions
> before him do not arise his rage. If they do, or if he is dead, it is
> necessary to seek God’s forgiveness to him.
>
> The Prophet (S) said: “The penance of backbiting is to seek Allah’s
> forgiveness to him the backbitten- whenever you mention him8.”

Reference:  [Backbiting](https://www.al-islam.org/ahlul-bayt-ethical-role-models-sayyid-mahdi-sadr/backbiting)